# jQuery validation not working even with name attributes set properly

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-validate

Need some help figuring what is wrong with my code. Documentation and all search I did stated the same thing: name attribute MUST be set for validation work. The problem is all my name attributes are set but it still not validating. And I did the same steps on other forms and it worked no problems. So I'm at loss here. Any ideas?

Here's the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dpq94a3f/

Here's the HTML

```
<form name="insert" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fid">ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fid" id="fid">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fx">X axis</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fx" id="fx">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="fy">Y axis</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fy" id="fy">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="finfo">Info</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="finfo" id="finfo">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="send_data" id="send_data" >Send Data</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger float-right" name="reset_data" id="reset_data" >Reset Data</button>
  </form>
```

And here's jQuery validation rules

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#insert').validate({
    rules: {
            fid: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 8,
                pattern: /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/
      },
            fx: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 5,
                number: true
      },
            fy: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 5,
                number: true
      },
      finfo: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 255
      }
    },
    messages: {
            fid: {
                required: "Required field",
        maxlength: "Too many characters",
        pattern: "Wrong pattern"
      },
      fx: {
                required: "Required field",
        number: "Number only"
      },
            fy: {
                required: "Required field",
        number: "Number only"
      },
            finfo: {
                required: "Required field",
        maxlength: "Too many characters"
      }
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
      element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You're targeting the `form` element by `id`, but your `form` element contains no `id`.  Use `$('[name="insert"]')` for targeting the `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code select it by `$('#insert')`.

It should be:

```
<form id="insert" method="post">
```

And the name attribute should add to every fields in the form, otherwise that field will not submitted.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe it was so simple. I was too focused on the form elements that I forgot the form tag itself.

Comment: Question should be closed for the spelling mistake reason.

Answer (score -1):

You must have a way to select the element you cannot try to select it with the id insert and have no elements with the id  insert because it will return null and you cannot validate null